# Android, Java: Return 2 elements of an List of three elements

Tags: android, list, parsing, return

I have a `List` composed of 3 values that have been parsed from a XML. What I would like to do is to compare a specific value with the first value of the list and depending on what value it is returned the other 2 elements that match the first value.

This a XML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <TABLA Nom_Test="A_NUM_MED_01" Escala="APTITUD RAZ. CRITICO NUMÉRICO">
 <PUNTUACION>
  <VALOR>0</VALOR>
  <VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>1,2</VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>
  <VALOR_PS>14,4</VALOR_PS>
 </PUNTUACION>
 <PUNTUACION>
  <VALOR>1</VALOR>
  <VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>1,2</VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>
  <VALOR_PS>14,4</VALOR_PS>
```

For example if the value is 1 , it should return the other 2 values: 1,2 and 14,4.

I have this structure and this works fine:

```
 public XMLPullParserHandler() {
    puntuaciones = new ArrayList<Puntuacion>();
}

public List<Puntuacion> getPuntuacion() {
    return puntuaciones;
}

public List<Puntuacion> parse(InputStream is) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        parser = factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("PUNTUACION")) {
                    // create a new instance of employee
                    puntuacion = new Puntuacion();
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = parser.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("PUNTUACION")) {

                    puntuaciones.add(puntuacion);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR")) {
                    puntuacion.setValor((text));
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_TRANSFORMADO")) {
                    puntuacion.setValor_Transformado((text));
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("VALOR_PS")) {
                    puntuacion.setValor_PS((text));;

                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return puntuaciones;
}
```

}

In order to compare this I have tried the following solution but I don't know how to continue 
(Edited) How to get the positions 1 and 2 of the List?

```
public void Check() {
for (int i=0;i<=30;i++){
int index = puntuaciones.indexOf("1");
puntuaciones.get(index);
```

}

I would appreciate some help for this last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Puntuacion> myList = getPuntuacion();    
 for (Puntuacion tmpPunt : myList) {
      if ( Verbal.getRespuesta() == VALOR)
            return tmpPunt;
 }
```

`getRespuesta()` should return a `String` object and, in order to compare `String` value you have to use the `equals` method from `String` class

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem in this case.

Comment: what you want to achieve? I really do not understand what's your issue

Comment: Hi, for example in this code: <PUNTUACION>
  <VALOR>1</VALOR>
  <VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>1,2</VALOR_TRANSFORMADO>
  <VALOR_PS>14,4</VALOR_PS>   -- if the value is 1 I would like to get the other 2 values  which are 1,2 and 14,4